# The device Camera messes with the default Camera in a different level in Unreal

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, unreal-engine4, arcore

So I have an Android App and I essentially have two game modes. One game mode allows the user to use the AR mode and the other is a non-AR mode. The non-AR mode and AR modes work great by themselves and I have no problems. However, if I switch to AR mode and then go back to my menu and switch back to non-AR mode the camera is changed and not in its default transform/position. Is there a reason why this is happening? Does anyone know how to go about fixing this? I've tried resetting the camera and pawns at the end and beginnings of each level but neither works. Any other suggestions would also be appreciated.

How nonAr mode should look:
[image]

How it looks after coming from AR mode:
[image]

Comment: Do you have Screenshots which help in understanding the issue?

Comment: @PhilLab I've added screenshots if that will help.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. ARCore moves the game camera around based on the tracking. So it seems that you indeed have to reset it. Probably the reset code is wrong. Posting the reset code might help

Comment: But there is no reset code. There is no function that allows you to just reset the game camera. The camera believes it is in the correct spot. If I were to print the values it would say it is at 0,0,0.

Comment: I was referring to your statement " I've tried resetting the camera", maybe I misunderstood it. Does ``Camera.main.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(x,y,z);`` do anything meaningful in your case?

Comment: This is Unreal... not Unity. But yes I've reset the entire camera transform to 0 including position and rotation.

Comment: Ok, I see, I misread :-)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a known bug in Unreal. Still unresolved as of 4.21.0.

https://issues.unrealengine.com/issue/UE-62163